# Remove an lxml object from memory?

Tags: python-2.7, lxml

I'm trying to remove a huge lxml object from memory once it has been used.
I tried close() method but tree.close() return me an error message (it says tree object hasn't this method). Did someone know a good technique ?

```
    from lxml import etree as ET
    import gc
    path  = # insert a big xml path and filename here
    tree = ET.parse(path)
    # --- Here I use data in some way ---
    # now I don't use that tree anymore
    del tree
    gc.collect()
    # after this, data still in memory
```

Comment: How do you know it is still in memory? Also do you have any other references to objects in the tree?

Comment: I simply watch the process manager of windows, why ? I don't have any others references. I just use the xpath method so as get some elements, that's all

Comment: So you are not storing any element then?

Comment: the xml parsed take about 2Go in memory, that's a dictionary in fact. but what I only need is the words, not the xml structure, there is a lot of informations I don't need. So I get a set() containing 400.000 words. Anyway, if I don't do anything my process take the same place in memory that if I try to remove it using del and gc.collect() so I can easily conclude that tree hasn't been removed from memory, right ?

Comment: You mean if you just `tree = ET.parse(path)` and call `del tree gc.collect()`?

Comment: yes, you mean it should normally work like that ?

Comment: I'm still searching or a solution : ( anyone ?